# How can Android Stop Login through facebook when there is no email id

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I follow facebook docs for integrating the facebook login in my app and I also get email id from the graph API request. but I want that when there is no email id then login is restricted......
My LoginFrament is

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private View mView;
private TextInputLayout til_emailid, til_password;
private EditText et_emailid, et_password;
Boolean eye_open = false;
LoginButton btn_facebooklogin;
private Button btn_login;
Context mContext;
AccessToken accessToken;
AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
ProfileTracker profileTracker;
private CallbackManager mcallbackManager;
String username, password, fbemail;

public LoginFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getActivity();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mcallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    btn_facebooklogin = (LoginButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_facebooklogin);
   btn_facebooklogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
           "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
    btn_facebooklogin.setFragment(this);
    btn_facebooklogin.registerCallback(mcallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            loginResult.getAccessToken();
            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                        Log.v("facebook - profile", profile2.getName());
                        profileTracker.stopTracking();
                        profile.setCurrentProfile(profile2);
                    }
                };
            } else {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                Log.v("facebook - profile", profile.getFirstName());
            }
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                           try {
                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                String name = object.getString("name");
                                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                Utils.showToast(mContext, name+email+birthday+gender);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (mcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        return;
    } else {
        Utils.showToast(mContext, "NO Results from Activity");
    }
}
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:
            Login();
            break;
    }
}
```

Here I need facebook email if it's not there then login must not be happened...???

Answer (score 0):

If email is empty or null, then logout from facebook using below code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```